# Get Twitter Bootstrap navbar to load different pages, not just reference to divs on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to web development and I don't know all the terms. But basically I want to implement my website like getbootstrap.com --- i.e. when you click on Getting started, the webpage brings you to a different page (and resource I believe). My current website's navbar just has references to different divs on the same page. Can someone direct me to some resources to learn about how "pages" work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the url of the page in ahref

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="PUT HERE THE URL OF THE PAGE ">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What if I don't have a URL, I need to refer to a resource on the directory/server? Like so: `<a href="./getting-started">Getting started</a>` It looks like getting-started is placed at root however my implementations have not worked. What's behind the magic?

Comment: Ok. I have figured it out. I was referencing to an empty html as well as not having the file placed in the right directory.

Answer (score -1):

i think you're looking for the html  a tag

```
<a href="http://youtube.com"> youtube </a>
```

for more info , check this out:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp